# determine number of current Resque workers from within Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

In my Rails app, I'd like to pop up a window that shows the number of Resque workers currently running. This would mainly be so that I can warn users when there are no workers running.

I have the Resque admin app mounted like so in routes.rb:

```
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/admin/resque"
```

I see that there is a text file called `/admin/resque/stats.txt` that includes the following:

```
resque.pending=0 resque.processed+=8 resque.failed+=0 resque.workers=2 resque.working=0 queues.model_job_queue=0
```

Should I fetch this file and just parse it for the value of `resque.workers` or is there another, better method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd ask Resque directly for an array of workers and count the elements returned.

```
1.9.2-p290 :003 > Resque.workers.count
=> 12
```

This is exactly how resque gets the count to build `/resque/stats.txt`.

Hope this helps.